# Selenium test fail when asserting multi-line text

Tags: selenium, phpunit

I am writing a PHPUnit Selenium test and two strings are compared by `assertEquals()` :

How it looks on the website, lets call it `$web_string` :

```
Hello
World
```

`assertEquals()` to:

`"Hello\r\nWorld"`, which is a hard-coded string in the Test Case PHP file, and it fails.

I am getting `$web_string` by calling `byCssSelector("xxx")->text();`

Basically it is selecting a div which contains two `<p>` elements with `Hello` and `World` in it.

How should I do the assertion in this case? is the `\r\n` causing the problem? Is there any possible solution to this other than having to modify the HTML and changing the css selector? (e.g. select `Hello` , `World` and `assertEquals()` separately?

Comment: Would replacing `\r\n` with a space in `$web_string` be sufficient for your test?

Comment: No. I really want to know is there any way to test CRLF in Selenium, especially when <br> <p> and many other elements might create a 'CRLF'

Comment: You mean phpunit as that provides the assert functionality. Selenium will return data as it finds in the html. You can add to the expected string `\r\n` in the correct places, or split the text into array on the line break and verify each individually.